# What are DeFi Smart Accounts?

Tags: defi

What are DeFi Smart Accounts?
And how they are different from ethereum accounts?

It seems "Smart Accounts" is not exact thing, non-standard within Ethereum ecosystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DeFi Smart Accounts" is not standard terminology and probably invented by a single person or a single marketing agency. It is impossible to tell and does not mean anything without context.